# youtube fullscreen is pixelated (1080p,too)

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome, video

Left normal(from friend), Right(from me)
[image]

After reinstalling my computer with Win 8.1 even 1080p vids in fullscreen are pixelated. 
Or not interpolated. using latest Chrome version(Flash+HTML5 player) are pixelated, but Internet Explorer with HTML5 and Flash is working properly.
What is that and how to "repair" it?